# Python bottle serving same output to all different users

Tags: python, bottle

I am working on a bottle project the code is downloading videos from any website.the downloading process is ok but the problem is when two user use my website with two different video url the server downloads the files but if returning the fastly download i mean that which video download fast the code returning that video to all users. This is a problem because when two users use my website to download to different videos they must need the same video as they give the url.
So please help me to separate all users.
So I need like, for every user my server will return the video for which they paste the url. I used threading server paste.
Please help me to find out how can i do that.

```
from bottle import route, run,request,static_file

import os
try:
    import youtube_dl
    
except:
    os.system('pip install youtube_dl')
    import youtube_dl
x=[]
def cvtmp3(filename):
        
        p=filename.split('.')
        print(p)
        a=p[0]
        audio=a+'.mp3'
        os.rename(filename,audio)
        print(audio)
        
        
def download(url):
    global filename
#   url=input('type the valid url: ')
    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
    os.chdir('/storage/emulated/0/')
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        #p=ydl.extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06H7OcPd-g')
        #print(p)
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        filename = ydl.prepare_filename(info)
        #ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06H7OcPd-g'])


@route('/')
def index():
    return '''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>paste any video link to download</h2>
    <form action="/submit" method="post">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" onclick="show()">
</form>
<div class="loader" style="display:none;"></div>
<script>
function show(){
document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerText="Please wait :) you will be redirected to download page ";
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.display="none";
document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display="block";}
</script>


'''
@route('/submit',method='POST')

def submit():
    #return "<h1>processing url</h1>"
    
    try:
        
        text=request.forms.get('text')
        if ',' in text:
            urls=text.split(',')
        else:urls=text.split('\n')
    except:pass
    global filename
    x=urls
    for url in urls:
        download(url.strip())
        #return "<h1>processing url</h1>"
    return '''<h1>processing done !!!</h1><br/><a href="/downloading">download</a> '''
    
    #%(os.getcwd()+'/'+filename)
@route('/downloading')

def downloading():
    global urls
    #for i in range(len(x)):
        #print('hao',i)
        #return 'halo'+str(i)
    return static_file(filename, root=os.getcwd(), download=True)

run(port=8080)
```

I hosted this on my mobile phone so you can check it if you have two mobile phone. But some times the urls can be changed
[Link of the website](http://ua-190bdb85.localhost.run)

Comment: when use send url then you should keep it in database with unique number - and send this unique number to client (as cookie or HTML or in url) - and client should use this unique number to access only its video. This way works many portal - ie YouTube or pastebin.org -  when you send file on YT or to pastebin then it gives you url with unique number to access this file.

Comment: Step one: get rid of your global variables. For instance, since `filename` is a global, all requests are going to be sharing the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `YouTube` you should generate urls with unique values - i.e. some unique number, unique number from YouTube url, name of downloaded file, etc.

```
/downloading?number=...

/downloading?filename=...
```

or

```
/downloading/<number>

/downloading/<filename>
```

and function `downloading` should use it to send correct file.

---

If you use filename then you don't need other variables. But it may not be safe because someone may use full path to file with password.

---

If you use unique number from YouTube url then you have to remeber it with originaml filename in database or at least in global variable

```
database[unique_number] = filename
```

and later `downloading` can use this unique number to send correct filename.

---

Because user may give many urls so you should use `for`-loop to generate link to `downloading` for every file separatelly.

---

Minimal working code

```
from bottle import route, run, request, static_file, template

import os
try:
    import youtube_dl
except:
    os.system('pip install youtube_dl')
    import youtube_dl
   
# --- functions ---
        
def download(url):
    ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
    #os.chdir('/storage/emulated/0/')
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        number = info['id']
        filename = ydl.prepare_filename(info)
        return number, filename
        
# --- pages ---

@route('/')
def index():
    return '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>paste any video link to download</h2>
    <form action="/submit" method="post">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea></br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="show()">
</form>
<div class="loader" style="display:none;"></div>
<script>
function show(){
document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].innerText="Please wait :) you will be redirected to download page ";
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.display="none";
document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display="block";}
</script>
'''


@route('/submit', method='POST')
def submit():
    try:
        text = request.forms.get('text')
        if ',' in text:
            urls = text.split(',')
        else:
            urls = text.split('\n')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('[Exception]', ex)

    all_items = []
    
    for url in urls:
        url = url.strip()
        number, filename = download(url)
        database[number] = filename
        all_items.append( (number, filename) )

    return template('''<h1>processing done !!!</h1><br/>
% for number, filename,  in items:
      Download: <a href="/downloading/{{number}}">{{filename}}</a></br>
% end
''', items=all_items)

    
@route('/downloading/')   # to catch url without number
@route('/downloading/<number>')
def downloading(number=None):
    if (not number) or (number not in database):
        return "WRONG NUMBER"
        
    filename = database[number]
    print('filename:', filename)

    return static_file(filename, root=os.getcwd(), download=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    database = dict()
    
    run(port=8080)
```